# SDO_GEOMETRY is not specified or is invalid

Tags: c#, oracle

I am attempting to fill a dataset from an oracle table. I am getting the following error:

**SDO_GEOMETRY is not specified or is invalid**

When I attempt to fill a dataset from a table which contains a geometry column:

```
da.Fill(ds, "Default");
```

I have added a reference to [NetSdoGeometry](https://github.com/mapspiral/NetSdoGeometry)

And also included it:

```
using NetSdoGeometry;
```

But I still receive the same error.

I also tried adding the type to the config as follows:

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="sdogeometry" value="udtMapping factoryName='NetSdoGeometry.sdogeometry, NetSdoGeometry, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' typeName='SDO_GEOMETRY' schemaName='MDSYS'"/>
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

But that did not help.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem.
We used NetTopologySuit insted of NetSdoGeomtry and included:

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
  <settings>
    <add name="SdoGeometry" value="udtMapping factoryName='NetTopologySuite.IO.Sdo.SdoGeometry, NetTopologySuite.IO.Oracle' typeName='SDO_GEOMETRY' schemaName='MDSYS'" />
    <add name="SdoElemInfoArray" value="udtMapping factoryName='NetTopologySuite.IO.Sdo.SdoGeometry+ElemArrayFactory, NetTopologySuite.IO.Oracle' typeName='SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY' schemaName='MDSYS'" />
    <add name="SdoOrdinateArray" value="udtMapping factoryName='NetTopologySuite.IO.Sdo.SdoGeometry+OrdinatesArrayFactory, NetTopologySuite.IO.Oracle' typeName='SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY' schemaName='MDSYS'" />
    <add name="SdoPoint" value="udtMapping factoryName='NetTopologySuite.IO.Sdo.SdoPoint, NetTopologySuite.IO.Oracle' typeName='SDO_POINT_TYPE' schemaName='MDSYS'" />
  </setting>
</oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

(this is taken from [NullReferenceException in Oracle.DataAccess for empty SDO_GEOMETRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594697/nullreferenceexception-in-oracle-dataaccess-for-empty-sdo-geometry) Although this is about another problem, udtMapping is correct and worked for us.)